# android app with apache cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications

I'm developing a web app using HTML5,CSS3 and JavaScript.
Then I want to use the Apache ordova platform to generate a native android app from my web app but I still don't understand what do I need for this,specially do I need a server-side development with php for example??

Comment: If your browser app requires a server than your mobile app probably will require a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off i suggest you read [this](http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/)
Pretty much your app will be able to accomplish a little bit more than what you would be able to do in a browser if all you had available was the ability to write html/js*.

*by this i mean that you have access to device-specific hardware which is not available in a browser and a few more things but pretty much that's it.

You will need to install node.js (or io.js), then install cordova through npm, and make sure you have the Android SDK installed. Once you create your project, your html/css/js will be wrapped into a native webview component, you do not need any server to render it, effectively your app is a native app that can be installed from google play.

You will need a server, typically a RESTful API, if your app needs to query data remotely or persist to some third party. If you are thinking through a classic MVC mindset (render a page through some php code) then you probably need to read about cordova and how it works. A cordova app is a client-side only app, no server-side processing is possible unless through a network communication to a server you have access to on the internet. You can do persistence locally (to the android device) and even use a local database, but remember that this db exists on the device, so you won't be able to share information between users unless you somehow coordinate that through your app (and most likely a server-side app / rest api).

It is unlikely that your existing web app can be wrapped into a cordova app straight away, cordova apps are single page apps mostly.

Comment: thanks for your precious information I do appreciate your help.
In my web Application I'll need images and sounds I don't understand where will I store those resources for the android app.

Comment: the same way you would in a plain html/js app. I normally use images/ and media/ folders containing assets. Look at [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/#project-directory-structure) for the generated directory structure by cordova, and remember to accept the answer if it satisfies your question.